# Variable doesn't get input text value

Tags: html, jsp

I have:

```
  <%
  int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("addd")); 
  %>
```

I want the variable contb in JSP to get the value of the HTML textbox "addd" but it gives an Exception. Can you help me?

Comment: Actually it is:

Comment: Actually it is: ```` <input type="text" name="addd" value="0"><br>
 <%
 int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("addd")); 
 %>  ````

Comment: But it dooesn't work

Comment: Add the Whole JSP code!

Comment: I want the variable contb to receive the value of the textbox whose name is addd. 
 I want contb to receive the value 0. ```` <input type="text" name="addd" value="0" id="ad3"><br>
 <%
  int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ad3")); 
 %>  ````

Answer (score 0):

I want the variable contb to receive the value of the textbox whose name is addd. 
    I want contb to receive the value 0.

`````
        int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ad3")); 
    %> ````
`````